# Issue with images not compiling properly

Tags: texstudio, includegraphics

Since I am starting to get the hang of LaTeX, I made a template for all of my notes in a stats class that has worked flawlessly so far.  All of a sudden, later images are not loading when I'm in TeXStudio (Mac).  The whole document compiles with no errors:

See images below.  This is odd... When I preview the compiled document in TeXStudio(IMG1/IMG2)- the typed problem shows up, but the image does not.  When I view the compiled PDF in Adobe Reader, the images show up, but the typed problem does not.(IMG3).  All images and text preceding this part of the document work without any issues.

Don't even know where to start.  I don't think I can write it off to user error, the document compiles with no problems and I don't seem to be missing anything.

[image: d]

[image: A screenshot of some code]

[image: Image of TexStudio Preview that corresponds to code in image 1]

Comment: Check how this ping behaves in a small example with some text. If is shows the same problem make the ping available somewhere.

Comment: could I have some further clarification? what's a ping/where can I go to learn more about it?

Comment: "a ping" is what a spell corrector makes of "png" if I don't pay attention.

Comment: hahah, thank you.

Comment: what a disaster.  long story short- issue resolved.  had nothing to do with latex.  Onedrive issue. thanks anyways.